# WPF DataGrid not populating with information from viewmodel (DataBinding not working)

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I have a `UserControl` named `TagGridView`, and a corresponding `TagGridViewModel` which holds an `ObservableCollection<TagViewModel>` to be displayed in the `DataGrid` using data binding. `TagViewModel` exposes some properties that I am trying to display in a `DataGrid`.

I created a button that adds an item to the `ObservableCollection<TagViewModel>` and shows a messagebox with the collection's item count and the data grid's item count. The collection is getting all of the items, except the `DataGrid` consistently says 0 for its count.

Here is the XAML code with the data binding:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Company.TagVisualizer.Views.TagGridView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Name="TagGrid" DataContext="{Binding Source=TagGridContext}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid Name="DataGridTag" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TagsCollection}" Margin="0" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Width="*"  Header="Selected" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="3*" Binding="{Binding Path=TagName}" Header="Tag Name"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="3*" Binding="{Binding Detections.Count}" Header="Detections"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="3*" Binding="{Binding EarliestDetection}"  Header="Earliest Detection"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="3*" Binding="{Binding LatestDetection}" Header="Latest Detection"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Content="Add" Click="Add_OnClick"/>
    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

Here is the codebehind file for the TagGridView:

```
public partial class TagGridView : UserControl
    {
        private TagGridViewModel _tagGridViewModel = new TagGridViewModel();

        public TagGridView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        public TagGridViewModel TagGridContext { get { return _tagGridViewModel; } set { _tagGridViewModel = value; } }

        private void Add_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TagGridContext.TagsCollection.Add(new TagViewModel("Boogie", 134.5, 145.8));

            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Items in collection: {0}\nItems in Grid: {1}", TagGridContext.TagsCollection.Count, DataGridTag.Items.Count));
        }
    }
```

Here is the `TagGridViewModel` class:

```
public class TagGridViewModel
    {
        private ObservableCollection<TagViewModel> _tagsCollection = new ObservableCollection<TagViewModel>();

        public ObservableCollection<TagViewModel> TagsCollection
        {
            get { return _tagsCollection; }
            set
            {
                _tagsCollection = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure what's going on. I have tried setting the DataContext in the `UserControl` tag and the `DataGrid` tag. No matter what I do, the DataGrid does not add any items to itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is usercontrol Datacontext problem. Please refer the below code for databinding.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Tags_Learning.TagGridView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" **DataContext="{Binding Path=TagGridContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"**>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid Name="DataGridTag" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TagsCollection}" Margin="0" 
              CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Width="*"  Header="Selected" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="3*" Binding="{Binding Path=TagName}" Header="Tag Name"/>                
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="3*" Binding="{Binding EarliestDetection}"  Header="Earliest Detection"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="3*" Binding="{Binding LatestDetection}" Header="Latest Detection"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Content="Add" Click="Add_OnClick"/>
</Grid>
```